# Backpressed and returning to application adds same list

Tags: android

I am creating audio player in which I have only one fragment. This fragment contains list of songs that are present in device. When I press back button it works well by leaving application. But when I return to application same list of songs is added in that list so I am getting two songs with same name and thus no of songs in list gets double.

Is there any solution to this?

I want list to remain same when i return to my application.

Comment: simply check if your method calls again on reload then first clear the list or do not let it call again.

Comment: Are you populating your list in `onResume` or `onStart`? Show some code please.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Override your back button and clear your list first in onBackPressed() and then go to previous activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override your back button and clear your list first in onBackPressed() and then go to previous activity

```
public void onBackPressed(){
yourlist.clear();
startAvtivity(new Intent(getContext(),ActivityYouWantGo.class));
}
```